# Computer restarts while downloading Ubuntu

Tags: 12.10, 13.04, windows-8, downloads, iso

I have a question.
While downloading the Ubuntu ISO file, my computer restarts randomly. Why does this happen? What should I do? The browsers I have tried are Firefox and Chrome. I use Windows 8. I have tried both the versions 13.04 and 12.10. Please help me.
And is there a way to legally torrent Ubuntu?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Windows restarts while downloading a file? This probably isn't a problem with Ubuntu. Can you download other big files?

Comment: Yes. I regularly download files as big as 6GB. But not through browsers.

Comment: Do you have a torrent client you can download with?

Comment: Of course torrenting Ubuntu is legal, as it's free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably a problem with your web browser and big file downloads.

I suggest trying the torrent downloads:

13.04 64-bit: http://releases.ubuntu.com/raring/ubuntu-13.04-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent

12.04 64-bit: http://releases.ubuntu.com/quantal/ubuntu-12.10-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent

You can look at all the downloads for  13.04 here: http://releases.ubuntu.com/raring/

And for 12.04 here: http://releases.ubuntu.com/quantal/

I do not know the cause of windows randomly restarting during downloads of big files, but the torrents should work if the regular downloads do not.